# How to constrain the format of strings ggplots and interaction generate to find colors in a named color vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggplot2` cannot find the color I generate, intended for parts of the bar diagram I want to generate.

The problem comes from the way `ggplot2` converts numbers from group and fill parameters in aes() to generates strings that are used as keys to find the correct color in the named color vector I generate.

It appears that the large numbers involved in my plots are turned into scientific notation, cutting all right-most decimal zeros from the converted string, whereas the keys in the named color vector I generate provide always keep the 2 first digits.

*I give below a simple example that illustrates my problem*

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(ggplot2)

frame = data.frame(
varA = c(5, 5, 5),
varB = c(1, 2, 3),
varC = as.factor(c(
    4e+08,
    1.05e+09,
    1.75e+09
)),
varD = c(1, 1, 1)
)

colors = c("#BB0000", "#00BB00", "#0000BB")
names(colors) = c("4.00e+08.1", "1.05e+09.1", "1.75e+09.1")

plot = ggplot() +
    guides(
        fill     = guide_legend(title = "varA")
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(
        values = colors
    ) +
    geom_bar(
        data = frame,
        aes(
            varA,
            varB,
            group = interaction(varC, varD),
            fill = interaction(varC, varD)
        ),
        position = "dodge",
        stat = "identity"
    )
ggsave(file = "plot.svg", plot = plot, width = 4, height = 3)
```

which results in this figure:

[image: The first bar should be red, but it has no color at all]

An obvious solution to this simple example would be to fix the key for red into "4e+08" instead of "4.00e+08", but that would not work in my full-blown use case. First because I do not hard code the colors but I generate them from the context in which I run this script. Second because I observed that sometime ggplot2 preserves some of my numbers as plain integers, sometimes it converts some other into scientific notation and I don't know what are the rules about this decision.

As I see it, there are two solutions.

- The first one would be to make sure that I generate color vector keys that will be the same as ggplot2 looks for colors. It implies that I can mitigate the second problem Identified above, with documentation I failed to find.
- The second (preferred) solution would be to constrain the way ggplot2 formats the color key string it uses so that it fits the named color vector I provide. I suspect this second solution is the same as constraining the way ggplot2 generate strings in the legend (more specifically, how it treats number formats) but I could not find any information about that either.

I am aware that I can give ggplot2 a simple vector of colors and it will fetch colors in the same order as it orders each bar. I cannot accept it as I want to make sure that all colors are consistent from plot to plot, even if I choose to show or to hide some bars in some of them.

*My question is therefore*:

- How can I constraint ggplots, probably via geom_bar() and/or interaction() so that I looks for colors the way I need it to?
- If this is not possible, where can I find how ggplot2 precisely converts (or does not convert) big numbers into scientific notations so I can generate correct name color vectors?

  ---

  Version information :
- `R` v3.4.1
- `ggplot2` v2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot` is not really at fault here. The behavior is caused by the `interaction` function, which creates a factor. More directly, it is caused by `factor` (which underlies `interaction`), which in turn simply calls `as.character`. See:

```
> as.character(frame$varC)
[1] "4e+08"    "1.05e+09" "1.75e+09"
```

This should solve your problems:

```
frame$group <- interaction(frame$varC, frame$varD)

colors <- setNames(c("#BB0000", "#00BB00", "#0000BB"), levels(frame$group))

ggplot(frame, aes(varA, varB, group = group, fill = group)) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your fix is the same as providing a keyless color vector and let ggplot2 to pick colors in order as it needs new one, which is not OK to me. Inspecting the code of interaction, I can see as.factor() and levels() that probably result in my problem. I can't see options I can pass to make as.factor to format number as I wish, but it's worth a try to explore more. In the worst case I know that my keys have to comply with whatever as.factor() does. Thanks

Comment: How about  `factor(frame$varC, labels = format(frame$varC, digits = 3))`?

Comment: Or `factor(frame$varC, labels = format(as.numeric(as.character(frame$varC)), digits = 3))` if you still want to start with `frame$varC` being a factor).